# Store value of some property during test execution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, automated-tests, trace

I have started to work with Unit Testing in Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0.

Some of our tests fail if a value is below a certain threshold, and then we plan to design the proper exception.

For example, let's suppose some method is expected to return a value greater than 10. I run the tests, and when I open the automatically saved `.trx` file, it says the test failed.

What I want to know is:

> Is there a way to save property values during a test, so that I can know their values after the test list execution has finished?

Comment: Why not just print out the value? It would be visible in the output log seen when opening up the .trx

Answer (score 0):

Here are some resources that explain the different ways to [log values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/12/08/logging-a-message-in-test-result-as-part-of-an-automated-test.aspx). from the link:

```
          [TestMethod]
             public void CodedUITestMethod1()
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Console.WriteLine()");
                 Console.Error.WriteLine("Console.Error.WriteLine()");
                 TestContext.WriteLine("TestContext.WriteLine()");
                 Trace.WriteLine("Trace.WriteLine()");
                 Debug.WriteLine("Debug.WriteLine()");
             }
```

Keep in mind they are not captured during run time, but flushed at the end, so if there is an unhandled exception the values may be lost. In this case we send key values to a DB or file as a backup.